# Remove button wont remove last created card

Tags: javascript

I have a function that adds event listeners to all the buttons on created cards, but they only remove up to the last created card?

```
DOMSelectors ={
    form: document.querySelector("#form"),
    itemname: document.querySelector("#item-name"),
    parent: document.querySelector(".container"),
}
async function getData(){
    let thing = DOMSelectors.itemname.value.toLowerCase();
    thing = thing.replaceAll(' ','-')
    let URL = `https://www.dnd5eapi.co/api/spells/${thing}`; 
    console.log(URL)
    try {
        const response = await fetch(URL);
        console.log(response);
    if (response.status !=200){
        throw new Error(response.statusText);
    }
    const data = await response.json(); 
    let id = ""
    if(data.hasOwnProperty("damage")){
        id = data.damage.damage_type.index
    }else if(data.hasOwnProperty("heal_at_slot_level")){
        id= "heal"
    }else{
        id=data.school.index
    }
    console.log(data.name, id);
   DOMSelectors.parent.insertAdjacentHTML(
        "beforeend",
        `<div class='card' id=${id}>
        <h2 id="name" class="name">${data.name}</h2>
        <h3 id="price" class="name">${data.desc}</h3>
        <button class="btn">REMOVE</button>
        </div>`
    )
    } catch (error){
       alert("Enter a valid spell")
    }
}
function clearfields(){
    DOMSelectors.itemname.value = ''
}
DOMSelectors.form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    getData();
    clearfields();
    byebye()
});
function byebye(){
    let buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".btn")
    buttons.forEach((btn)=> btn.addEventListener('click', function(event){
        btn.parentElement.remove();
    }))
}
```

this is the code so far its the byebye function that should remove the cards

ive used an identical function with the same purpose on a different project and it worked so i tried to just replicate the conditions and nothing happened

Comment: try moving the `byebye` function call inside the `getData` function after you have inserted the new card into the DOM

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be related to how you are removing the cards. Currently, your byebye function is adding event listeners to existing buttons, but if you create new cards after adding these listeners, the new buttons won't have listeners associated with them.

To address this, you can modify the byebye function to add an event listener to the parent container (.container) instead of each individual button. This is known as event delegation. This way, events from child buttons will also be handled, even for dynamically created buttons. Here's a modified version of your byebye function:

```
function byebye() {
DOMSelectors.parent.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if (event.target.classList.contains('btn')) {
        event.target.parentElement.remove();
    }
})}
```

In this version, the event listener is added to the parent container (DOMSelectors.parent). When a click occurs inside this container, the function checks if the event target (the clicked element) has the class "btn" (a button). If so, it removes the parent of that button, which is the card you want to delete.

This approach should work for both existing and future buttons, ensuring that all buttons within the specified container are handled, regardless of when they were created.